# Updating current list from one controller to another in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Im having issues updating a list. I have tried both rootscope and using factory but it just doensn't update the view. Rather it remains the same. The only time the update works is if the list is empty to begin with otherwise the original load is always there. Appreciate any suggestions.

Here is my attempt using rootscope:

rootscope alternative

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

                $routeProvider
                    .when('/',{
                        replace:true,
                        templateUrl: 'views/questions.html',
                        controller: 'SiteController as vm'
                    })
                    .when('/categories',{
                        templateUrl: 'views/categories.html',
                        controller: 'CategoriesCtrl as cm'
                    })
                    .when('/categories/:name*',{
                        templateUrl: 'views/questions.html',
                        controller: 'SiteController as vm'
                    })

                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    })
            }]);
```

index.html

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8" ng-view>
               All views load here
 </div>
```

questions.html

```
<table class="table table-questions">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

 <tr dir-paginate-start="q in vm.allquestions>
            <td>

                <a class="questionlinks" ng-click="vm.viewquestion(q.idquestion)> {{q.question}} </a><h4></h4>{{q.date }}
            </td>
            <td  class="text-center"><span class="box box-blue"> {{q.clicks}} </span></td>

        </tr >
 </tbody>
    </table>
```

categories.html

```
<div class="wrapper content content-categories content-tags" id="categories_content">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="list-tags" ng-repeat="c in cm.categories">
            <li><a ng-href="#/categories{{c.categoryurl}}" ng-click="cm.getCategoryQuestions(c.idcategory)">{{c.categoryname}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div >
```

Now the controllers 
SiteController

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
       .module('app')
        .controller('SiteController', SiteController);

    SiteController.$inject = ['$http','$route','$routeParams','$rootScope'];

    function SiteController($http,$route,$routeParams,$rootScope) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.allquestions=[];

        vm.thequestions=thequestions;

 init();

        function init(){
            thequestions();  
        }

function thequestions() {
            var url;
            $rootScope.$on('updateQs',function(event, obj){

                url=obj;
                $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    vm.allquestions=response.data;
                });
            });
                $http.get("/getlatestquestions").then(function (response) {
                    vm.allquestions=response.data;

                });
        }
    }
})();
```

Categories Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('CategoriesCtrl', CategoriesCtrl);

    CategoriesCtrl.$inject = ['$http','$rootScope'];

    function CategoriesCtrl($http,$rootScope) {

        var cm = this;
        cm.categories=[];
        cm.categoryquestions=[];

        //CATEGORIES
        cm.getCategories=getCategories;
        cm.getCategoryQuestions= getCategoryQuestions;

        init();

        function init(){
            getCategories();
        }

        //CATEGORIES RELATED
        function getCategories() {
            var url="/getcategories";
            var categoryPromise=$http.get(url);
            categoryPromise.then(function (response) {
                cm.categories=response.data;
            })
        }

       function getCategoryQuestions(idcategory) {
            var url="/getcategoryquestions"+idcategory;
                $rootScope.$emit('updateQs',url);
        }
    }
})();
```

Factory alternative
Added this in the app.module file under app.config

```
  app.factory("newquestions", function () {

                var questions = {};

                return {
                    setQs: function (value) {
                        questions = value;
                    },
                    getQs: function () {  
                        return questions;
                    }
                };
            });
```

This in SiteController

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
       .module('app')
        .controller('SiteController', SiteController);

    SiteController.$inject = ['$http','$route','$routeParams','newquestions'];



    function SiteController($http,$route,$routeParams,newquestions) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.allquestions=[];

        vm.thequestions=thequestions;

 init();

        function init(){

        initial();
            thequestions();

        }

 function initial(){
           newquestions.setQs("/getlatestquestions");
        }

        function thequestions() {
            var url=newquestions.getQs();

            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                vm.allquestions=response.data;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

This in CategoriesController

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('CategoriesCtrl', CategoriesCtrl);

    CategoriesCtrl.$inject = ['$http','newquestions'];

    function CategoriesCtrl($http,newquestions) {

        var cm = this;
        cm.categories=[];
        cm.categoryquestions=[];

        //CATEGORIES
        cm.getCategories=getCategories;
        cm.getCategoryQuestions= getCategoryQuestions;

        init();
        function init(){
            getCategories();
        }
        //CATEGORIES RELATED
        function getCategories() {
            var url="/getcategories";
            var categoryPromise=$http.get(url);
            categoryPromise.then(function (response) {
                cm.categories=response.data;
            })
        }
       function getCategoryQuestions(idcategory) {
            var url="/getcategoryquestions"+idcategory;
                newquestions.setQs(url);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I feel like you are approaching this in the wrong way.  Controllers can only communicate between each other **if they are both on the page at the same time**.  Generally, you either use a service which is a singleton to hold the data between page transitions, you update the server before each transition, or you store and retrieve your data state from localstorage/cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work. There is no way to know either of your controllers to know that list has changed.

**Solution**
Use event broadcasts.
Broadcast or emit an event from two controllers. And use it as a trigger point.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the first controller has to load data on initiation for one view. Then the second controller has to update that data, but since we are using the first controller for that same view the inital data is also loaded again and the second controllers data is visible for like 1 sec and then is replaced. It feels like "what came first, the chicken or the egg" type of problem. I think the problem is that im trying to use two controllers and manipulate the same view.